# Conditional distribution of Ornstein-Uhlenbeck on two fixed points

Tags: distributions, stochastic-processes, autoregressive, kriging

The conditional distribution of a Ornstein-Uhlenbeck $X(t)$ conditional on $X(0)$ is given by

> $$
> X(t)|X(0) = X(0)e^{-t} + \mu(1 - e^{-t})
> $$

This process is usually only defined for $t>0$ (future values), but I see no reason why this shouldn't extend backwards as well:

$$
X(|t|)|X(0) = X(0)e^{-|t|} + \mu(1 - e^{-|t|})
$$

However, I was wondering if this can also be extended between *two* points as well. I know this is done in kriging, but I was wondering if something similar can be applicable here as well:

$$
X(t)|X(a),X(b) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
X(a)e^{-(a-t)} + \mu(1 - e^{-(a-t)}) & t < a
\\ \color{red}{???} & a < t < b
\\ X(b)e^{-(t-b)} + \mu(1 - e^{-(t-b)}) & b < t
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

Comment: Yes, you just need to apply https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions